# How to pass dynamic value between action Struts2 REST Annnotation?

Tags: java, struts2

The order is generated in PaymentController then sent to ThankyouController

```
@Results({
    @Result(name="create",  type="redirectAction", 
            params = {"actionName" , "thankyou", "order", "${order}"})
})
public class PaymentController {
    private Order order;

    public Order getOrder()
        return order;

    public void setOrder(Order order)
        this.order = order;

    public String create()
        order = generateOrder();
        return "create";
}



public class ThankyouController
    private Order order;

    public HttpHeaders index()
    {
        System.out.println("---------------------" + order + "-----------------------------");
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders("index").withStatus(200);
    }

    public Order getOrder()
        return order;

    public void setOrder(Order order)
        this.order = order;
```

But for some reasons I keep getting Null value in the ThankyouController.

Could anyone suggest me a correct way to pass value between actions without using session ?

Comment: You can't send objects like that; it's still an HTTP redirect.

Comment: Persist the order and then return an id which the next action can look up. Or use ajax on the client side to merge both forms into one if you don't want an intermediate step and send the data at once. There are other ways such as using the session but i think they're more work and risk complications... people like me try to open dozens of windows into an application at one time, you can of course account for this too but designing in a way that makes such complications a non issue from the start is probably best.